# Kotlin - How to get 5(or selected numbers) random Char from charRange '0..'z'

Tags: string, kotlin, random, char, return

Did you know to get 5(or selected Number) random char from a Range '0..'z' ??
In "fun putCharTogehter" must call with specific numbers and must put these Char to new String with + Operator and then return to "fun main" with complete strong that is have size 5 or selected

In concept i know how to do but yeah only in concept.

**Wish output Example: 38dj(**

```
fun main() {

    println(putCharTogehter(5))


}


fun putCharTogehter(stringSize: Int): String {
    var charRange = ('0'..'z').random()
    return charRange.toString()

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want characters in range '0' to 'z'? This range contains a lot of special characters as well in case you didn't notice that.

Comment: @ArpitShukla They have a special character in their example output.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Oh, right. Had missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by first creating array of chars and then converting it to a string:

```kotlin
fun putCharTogehter(stringSize: Int): String {
    return CharArray(stringSize) {
        ('0'..'z').random()
    }.concatToString()
}
```

Comment: thx for answer. How this code it would look with null safety and + operator?

Comment: Using `+` is a really bad idea as it would copy the whole string each time we add a new char to it. If you really prefer `+` then you can do this with a classic loop or using `fold()`. I'm not sure what do you mean regarding null safety.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option:

```
fun putCharTogether(stringSize: Int): String = buildString {
    repeat(stringSize) { 
        append(('0'..'z').random())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```kotlin
fun putCharTogether(stringSize: Int): String {
    return (1..stringSize).joinToString("") { ('0'..'z').random().toString() }
}
```

OR

```kotlin
fun putCharTogether(stringSize: Int): String {
    return (1..stringSize).map { ('0'..'z').random() }.joinToString("")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
val charRange = ('0'..'z')
val randomChars = generateSequence { charRange.random() }
randomChars.take(5).joinToString("").run(::println)
```

You could make it shorter, but the point is you can put together a `sequence` that's basically a neverending source of random chars, and just `take` from that as you need them. And you can easily put together a pipeline that, say, `drop`s certain chars you need to exclude in a given situation, or whatever other processing you need. Depends on the situation but it can be a nice approach for composing things